# Javascript prototyped inheritance

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [Crockford's book on Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) and trying its inheritance method "Beget", but I'm puzzled by the result.

Could you explain why the following code returns "Values: blue_small / **blue**_big"? I would expect it to return "Values: blue_small / **red**_big".

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
   Object.beget = function (o) {
      var F = function () {};
      F.prototype = o;
      return new F();
   };
}

function calculate(){  
    var object1 = {
        color: "red",
        size: "small"
    };

    var object2 = Object.beget(object1);

    object2.size = "big";

    object1.color = "blue";

    return "Values: "+object1.color +"_" + object1.size +" \/ " + object2.color+"_" + object2.size || "unknown";
}
```

Comment: Do `console.dir(object2)` and have a look at the prototype chain. `object1` is the prototype of `object2`, so every change you make to `object1` is also reflected in `object2` (unless `object2` shadows a property of `object1`). Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Crockford has called object.create returning a clone but that's completely missing the point of prototype. MDN has clone in quotes. What prototype is is explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: What he calls classical inheritance he always does wrong and then criticizes it for the things he does wrong. He insists on privates but breaks encapsulation by changing objects he doesn't own: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, when the value of a property is **not** set on an instance, getting the value refers to the prototype chain.

In this example, the `object2` is created and `object1` is its prototype. But the value of the `color` property is never set on `object2` in an explicit way.

This means that reading the value refers to the prototype which is `object1` and since the value there is set to `blue`, you have the result.

Your confusion probably stems from the fact that you would expect creating new object to create a **copy** that includes all properties. In fact however, the newly created object has no properties set in an explicit way. Whenever you **get** a value of a property, prototype chain is referred.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! You fully clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your object2 inherits from your object1.

#### First step

`object1 = { color: "red", size: "small" };` => object 1 = red/small

#### Second step

`var object2 = Object.beget(object1);` => object 2 = red/small

#### Third step

`object2.size = "big";` => object 2 = red/big

#### Fourth step

`object1.color = "blue";` => object 1 = blue/small **and** object 2 = blue/big

#### Why that?

Because you've never changed the Object 2 color, so it will get the color from Object 1, who is its father. So, when you change Object 1, the Object 2 will automatically update this property. If, at any time, you had changed the Object 2 color, then, it would bypass the inheritance.

Comment: Actually `object2` will not automatically be updated when `object1.color` is set. The inheritance comes only into play when the `color` property is *read* from `object2`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `beget` does not create a copy of `object1`, but creates a new *empty* `object2` which *inherits* its properties from `object1`. This inheritance is dynamic, and when you change `object1` then that new property value is also visible on `object2`.